# Adding pod to Today extensions forces production of generic archive

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, ipa

I have stumbled upon a very strange problem.

In one of my apps I am using cocoa pods to install Alamofire. Up until today I was already adding Alamofire to my main target. However, I then decided to use Alamofire in 2 Today extensions which I have. I modified my Podfile to look like this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'target1' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
end

target 'target2' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
end

target 'target3' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Everything works fine when I am debugging the product. I can also confirm that Alamofire executes correctly in extensions. The problem is that whenever I archive my app I am getting generic archive with no specific membership to any project.

Upon inspection I can see that target2.appex (0 bytes) and target3.appex (0 bytes) are copied in Products directory of my archive. The correct versions also exist in Products/Applications/target1.app/Plugins . I have no clue how to resolve this.

I have already tried using link_with in my Pod file. I have also tried playing with some build settings - it still does not work.

Has anyone experienced this problem and knows how it can be fixed?

I can confirm that when I change my Pod file to

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    use_frameworks!

    target 'target1' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
    end

    target 'target2' do
    end

    target 'target3' do
    end
```

the created archive is correct. However, with such setup I cannot use Alamofire in my extensions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is an issue with Cocoapods and Xcode 7. This thread is the most helpful:

[Invalid archive produced when using "Archive" in Xcode 7 GM (with watchkit extension) #4021](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4021)

The most popular workaround is to delete the **Copy Pod Resources** phase from your Today Extension target (in Build Phases). I tried this and can confirm it works and keeps the pod I was using on my Today Extension working normally.

Other popular suggested workarounds are:

- Using CocoaPods 0.39.0.beta.3 and running pod install again
- Drag "Public" headers to "Project" for Header build phase in each Pod target.

See also: [Archives broken in Xcode 7β6 by containing public pod headers](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4119#issuecomment-137169818)